# Constrained to MS Access - Server Options

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am developing a small web app for a small amount of users within a university. It will be built as a complementary program for an Optical Mark Recognition machine that was custom built 20 years ago and will only work with an MS Access db. Unfortunately, we can't move this to a SQL Server db. I am new to this, so what are the options for accessing an Access db on a server, or the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Access is is a "database as a file" application, not a client-server solution, so you can simply put your mdb file on a share and access it from there. If you need to stick to Access you can :

- use the pages functionality in Access to generate web pages
- use the new App functionality in Access 2013, it seems it can act as a web app (don't know it much more)
- use the Access database as a front end and access SQL Server through it.

But if it was built 20 years ago, are you stuck with an old version of MS Access ?

Comment: Can't believe I only spotted the reply now and I'm on every day.Thanks for your reply. Yes in reality they are constrained to using Access. But I decided to just go with mySQL and let they can use a script to transfer the data every day or so. Thank god I didn't have to use Access!